# How to prevent bluetooth to restart paused videos/audio?

Tags: linux-mint, xorg, audio, bluetooth, bluez

I use Linux Mint Trica.

When I connect my main audio device by clicking `blueberry` in the toolbar (got it via `xprop`), my paused videos in my `firefox` tabs and `spotify` get restarted all together (to be more descriptive, only one browser tab is restarted).

Is there a fix, a workaround to prevent this not wanted behavior ?

- bluez 5.53
- blueberry 1.3.9